# How to Limit the hit-rate of connection for "X-Forwarded-for" IPs?

Tags: firewall, xforwarding, load-balancing

I have Apache, which is behind the Amazon ELB which forwards the IPs as in "X-Forwarded-for" header. I found some articles around to do the hitrate limitation but i doubt they are all for real IPs, not for "X-Forwarded-for".

I tried with "iptables" but surely didn't work.

Which is the way to do that please?